# Initializing variable/object in different methods vs initializing globally

Tags: java, object, logic

I want to use an object in my program in different functions.

case 1:

```
class a
{
public Scanner s; //the object
  method1()
  {
   s=new scanner(System.in);
   s.close();
  }

  method2()
  {
   s=new scanner(System.in);
   s.close();
  }
  p s main(String[] args)
 {
  method1();
  method2();
 }

}
```

case 2:

```
class a
{
public Scanner s=Scanner(System.in);
  method1()
  {
   //functions with s
  }

method2()
  {
      //functions with s

  } 

  main()
  {
  method1();
  method2();
  }

}
```

If I close the object in one function in CASE 1, I can't access it.
Which CASE is optimised? Which one should I use? Is it better to initialize them at the beginning?

Comment: Use case 1, since in each *methods* (In Java, they're called methods), you're going to use them, and I see, you'll also have to close them. So using case two wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: Please take the time to write real code and indent it properly. You're asking for help. You don't want to make people guess at what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the solution in `case1`

```
case 1: 
        class a 
        { 
            public Scanner s; //the object
            method1() 
            { 
                s=new scanner(System.in);
                s.close();
            } 

            method2() 
            { 
                s=new scanner(System.in);
                s.close();
            } 
            p s main(String[] args)
            { 
                method1(); 
                method2(); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: may i ask why you'll go with case1 any specific reason ?